# How long have they been dead?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-others

In the 2001 film 'The Others,' how long have Grace and the children been dead?

Anne mentions to Mrs. Mills that the servants left and then "Mummy went mad," and Grace mentions that the servants left a week ago.

Does this mean that the servants leaving her alone had pushed Grace over the edge, causing her to kill her kids and herself, and that they've only been dead for a week when Mrs. Mills shows up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think so as the car that family moving in are driving are 1930s (I think it's Christler Duesenberg).
[image]
Husband going and not comming back from second world war (1939-1945) and them knowing that war is over, would imply that it's around 1945+.
This then makes it probable that she indeed died only a while ago.

Comment: I don't recall, was it ever said that it was WWII and not WWI?